# How to protect sensible images/files from direct URL-Access via nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, server, authorization, backend

Hello fellow developers,

I am stuck with a (at least to me) challenging problem in NodeJS. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Consider a community webapp in React with a NodeJS-Backend and a MariahDB-DB. Each user can upload photos or videos in his or her personal album.
Only logged-in users are allowed to see it.

Now, the implementation is not hard on first view. But here comes the problem:

Once an logged-in user is shown the image-URL, he or her can access the image/file directly through the browser and even forward it to unauthorized persons.

To get some inspiration to solve this I have looked how Instagram does ist and they seem to append some kind of hash to their images. But I have not found further information  about that technique.

So, the question is: How can I prevent unauthorized direct access? What are best-practices?

Thanks so much in advance,

Wiwi

Comment: The common way is to use a long random URL that makes it next to impossible to guess a correct URL. Each images is assigned such a random URL saved in a database, just just have to be careful to use a good secure random for generation of the URLs, because if you use a weak random it can be guessed. Random part should have at least 128bit of entropy. Alternatively you could use the image content to generate the "random part", e.g. use a SHA1 or SHA256 of the image file.